# Add username in quick launch link

Tags: sharepoint-designer, wss-3.0

I want to add current logged userid in link of quick launch bar, with sharepoint designer 2007

Answer (score 1):

Use [SPServices Jquery from CodePlex](http://spservices.codeplex.com/), wherein adding

```
var thisUserName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "ID",
    debug: false
});
```

would get you the userid.

Check the [documentation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation) on how this can be done.

Comment: it is not working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

There are no out of the box ways to do this. You can probably use the welcome user control (modified just for showing the username) in the default.master and modify this master-page to add the control near the quick launch content placeholder.

Comment: welcome user control is showing the username but i want the userid

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current logged un user id out of the box. If you view source on any sharepoint page you should be able to see a Javascript object literal _spPageContextInfo

```
var _spPageContextInfo = { ..omited-code.. **userId:1**, ..omited-code...};
```

if you want to get that variable its as easy as

```
alert(_spPageContextInfo.userId);
```